# I want to linking function to variables

Tags: javascript, function, variables

```
var example = 'example value' ; 


function getVal() {

 // I want to take the above value;

    return this.value;
}

// I want to 
console.log( example.getVal() );
```

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.  But learn about `prototype`s.

Comment: It's not clear what you want that you can't get with `console.log(example)`

Answer (score 2):

A simple, basic approach is to create the function as a property of the "example" object.

```
var example = {
   value: 'example value',
   getVal: function() {
      return this.value;
   }
};

console.log(example.getVal());
```

Here is an example with multiple properties

```
var example = {
      value: 'example value',
      otherValue: 'other example value',
      getVal: function() {
         return this.value;
      },
      getOtherVal: function() {
         return this.otherValue;
      }
   };

   console.log(example.getVal());
   console.log(example.getOtherVal());
```

Of important note: you do not need a function to get the value of a property of an Object. the properties, in this example, are public. Therefore the values of the properties are accessible from the instance.

So the above example could be written like so...

```
 var example = {
          value: 'example value',
          otherValue: 'other example value'
       };

       console.log(example.value);
       console.log(example.otherValue);
```

It is recommended to learn about Object prototypes and create a reusable object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes

Comment: how to do other variables ?

Comment: The answer has been updated with more examples @SezerBölük

Answer (score 0):

Pass value as a function parameter

```
var example = 'example value' ; 
function getVal(str) {
    value=str;
    return value;
}
console.log(getVal(example));
```